# 112 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, linker-errors, duplicate-symbol

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Keychain in:
    /Users/anand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NIDA_Rooms-bawdeawpyzqrkjazbcspzbsqgrht/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GTMOAuth2/libGTMOAuth2.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
    /Users/anand/Documents/Anand_ios_Project/ROC&NIDAROOMS/ROCAPP 3/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
ld: 112 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Just remove framewrok from your project and clean it and add it again . your duplicate problem solve.

Comment: Update your question with a few more of the duplicate symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You link against `GoogleOpenSource.framework` and `libGTMOAuth2.a`. Both contain (define) the symbol `_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Keychain`. You should remove either the framework or the lib from linking.

Comment: How to fix it? cause I'm using this framework so cant delete.

Comment: Try to remove the library from the target settings of your project. The duplicate symbols errors should disappear, but missing symbols could appear. If that happen, add the library again and remove the framework. You cannot build your app with both, library and framework.

Comment: please nevgate how to do this in project

Comment: Look into the **target settings** of your app. There's a tab _General_ where you can find a section `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`. Select the framework and click the minus symbol below.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when an `implementation` is defined in the `.h` file.

Particularly in this case have a look at where does `GTMOAuth2Keychain` is define, and if it's in `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h`.

Fix it by moving the implementation to the `.mm/.m` file.